# Exception while saving to MySql DB

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm getting a strange non-deterministic (so it seems) exception while saving.

The saving function in controller:

```
for (cat in categories) {
    def recipeArray = recipeSource.getRecipes(cat)
        for(recipeString in recipeArray) {

            Recipe recipe

            def file = new File('recipes/'+recipeString+'.recipe')

            log.debug(recipeString+ ': Looking for recipe in DB')
            recipe = recipeService.findByName(recipeString)
            //recipe already in DB
            if(recipe){
                //add category to recipe
                log.debug('Recipe found. Adding category')
                recipeService.addCategory(recipe.id, cat)
            }
            else{
                log.debug(recipeString+ ': not found in DB')
                log.debug('Reading from disk...')

                try{

                        file.withObjectInputStream(getClass().classLoader){ois ->
                        recipe = ois.readObject()
                        println()
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    log.error('Error while reading recipe from disk: '+recipeString)
                    log.error(e)

                }

                if(!recipe){
                    log.debug('downloading...')
                    recipe = recipeSource.getRecipe(recipeString)
                    if(!recipe){
                        log.error('Recipe is null!')
                        skipped++
                        writeToDisk(file, recipe)
                        continue
                    }
                }
                else{
                    // file found but not in DB -> broken recipe
                    continue
                }



                for(Tag tag in Tags){
                    recipeService.addTag(recipe, tag)
                }

                //invalid data
                if(!validateRecipe(recipe)){
                    log.error('Recipe invalid: '+recipe.getName())
                    skipped++
                    writeToDisk(file, recipe)
                    continue
                }

                //EXCEPTION OCCURS IN THE LINE BELOW
                recipeService.addCategoryToRecipe(recipe, cat)

                writeToDisk(file, recipe)

                try{
                    log.debug('saving recipe...')
                    def catName = cat.getName()
                    recipeService.addTag(recipe, catName)
                    recipeService.saveRecipe(recipe)
                    log.debug('Recipe saved: '+recipe.getName())
                    total++
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    file.delete()
                    log.error('Error while savig recipe. Skipping..')
                    skipped++
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The service for saving:

```
@Transactional
class RecipeService {

    DataSource dataSource
    TagService tagService

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    def getRecipe(id){
        Recipe.get(id)
    }

    def saveRecipe(Recipe recipe){
        recipe.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    def findByName(String name){
        Recipe.findByName(name)
    }

    def addCategoryToRecipe(Recipe recipe, de.mysexybody.Category cat){
        recipe.addToCategories(cat)
    }

    def addCategory(Long recipeId, Long categoryId){
        def category = Category.get(categoryId)
        def recipe = Recipe.get(recipeId)
        recipe.addToCategories(category)
        recipe.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    }

    def addTag(Recipe recipe, String tagString){
        for(Tag t in recipe.getTags()){
            if(t.getName() == tagString){
                return
            }
        }
        def savedTag = tagService.findTagByName(tagString)
        if(!savedTag){
            savedTag = tagService.saveTag(tagString)
            if(!savedTag){
                log.error(savedTag.errors)
                throw new Exception("Tag error")
            }
        }
        recipe.addToTags(savedTag)
    }
}
```

And here is the exception:

```
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [10]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure16_closure17.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:184)
    at de.msb.RecipeController$$EOTUayCy.importRecipes(SportController.groovy:133)
    at de.msb.RecipeController$$EOTUayCy.index(SportController.groovy:20)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:151)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:282)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:203)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2014-01-20 15:01:34 [ERROR] PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [10]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure16_closure17.doCall(GrailsMelodyGrailsPlugin.groovy:184)
    at de.msb.RecipeController$$EOTUayCy.importRecipes(SportController.groovy:133)
    at de.msb.RecipeController$$EOTUayCy.index(SportController.groovy:20)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:200)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JspWrapper.invoke(JspWrapper.java:151)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:282)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:203)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Now the odd part. If I restart my application(or just the saving function) after this exception has occured, the object which has not been saved before makes no problems now.
Every time I restart, the application may save one or more objects and throw the same exception again.

In particaular it's a MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException but for whatever reason grails doesn't show it. I know what the exception is telling me, but I think it's just a side effect of an other error which seems to be swallowed by the app or the frameworks. I also tried to set the debug level to 'trace' but didn't find anything helpful.

What I have tried so far:

- Thoroughly validated all domain objects. I checked objects that could be saved and objects that led to the exception. They were all valid.
- Checked application's memory usage
- Checked DB processes

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The only thing that seems suspicious is that you set your recipe as `recipe = ois.readObject()`. Try to save it before adding categories.

Comment: The whole file handling serves only for backup purpose. In case I want to rerun the import, I don't need to download everything again. But I will remove it and try again.

Comment: maybe its because your service is transactional. you feed it objects returned from a separate call to your service, which are in different sessions. try for example change addCategoryToRecipe such that you only pass id. then retrieve again the object in that method so that you are sure that the objects are in same session. hope my explanation is not confusing.

Comment: I've found a solution for my Problem. I removed `addCategoryToRecipe` and everything works fine now. Though I have to iterate an other time and add categories.
Although I can complete my task now, I still want to know what is the cause of the problem.